# Angular Dart stepper

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I'm having issues with the Material Stepper for Angular Dart, I was trying to put it into my own app but just to test I copied the entire demo from :

https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/examples/material_stepper_example/lib/material_stepper_demo.dart

The issue is whenever I try to load that component I get this error EXCEPTION: No provider found for DomService: ScrollHost -> DomService.

As I said im getting that error with the working demo code, if anyone can assist that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/288

> The list item needs DomService which is an injectable.
>
> The easiest way to get it is to add the materialProviders to your
>   root. You can see that here:
>   https://webdev.dartlang.org/codelabs/angular_components/2-starteasy#--set-up-the-root-components-dart-file
>
> Thanks for using angular_components.

See also https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular_components/angular_components/materialProviders-constant

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `scrollHostProvider` is in your `@Component()`:

```
providers: [scrollHostProviders]
```